# Where can I read online the Vedanta Sutras along with commentaries of Ramanujacharya, Adi Shankaracharya and Madhvacharya in English?

Tags: vedanta, translation-request, brahma-sutras, ramanujacharya, madhvacharya

I am looking to read the Vedanta Sutras along with the commentaries of the 3 great acharyas of all time: Ramanujacharya, Adi Shankaracharaya and Madhvacharya, in English. Can somebody provide me with some links of the Vedanta Sutras along with the commentaries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **1.** Here is the link of The Vedanta-sutras, with the
>   [**Sri-bhashya**](https://archive.org/details/vedantasutraswit00badaiala) of **Shree Ramanujacharya :** You can Download as
>   well as can read the book Online.
>
> ---
>
> **2.** Here is the link of The Vedanta Sutras with the commentary by [**Sri Madhvacharya**](https://archive.org/details/BrahmasutraMadhvaEnglish) Same way you can download as well as can
>   read online.

---

As you requested here are some of the links of **Vedanta-Sutras with commentary of  Shree Adi Shankaracharya.**

> **1.** Here is the [**Wisdom Library**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras) link where you can read  “The Vedanta-Sutras”, with the commentary of  Shree Adi
>   Shankaracharya. Here you can read them online.
>
> **2.** Here is [**Sacred-texts**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34007.htm) link for the same

Comment: I have modified my question a little so do you have a link of Adi Shankaracharya's commentary as well?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury - Please find updated answer with Adi Shankaracharya's commentary links. :)

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury This time you have asked for clarification but from the next time, add all the details before you ask you want in the question and then accept the answer. :)